# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I am working on scenario in which there is an UI where user can come and add their Telegram `access token` and `verify token`  and I will setup the bot webhook to one of our other service [ let's say GPT-3 ]

Here is the problem statement

Now User A comes adds their access token and verify token in the UI, their webhook is connected
for example `https://[SERVER_URL]/webhooks/telegram/webhook?UID=CLIENT_A`

I open the telegram bot and start having conversation, It is working fine

Now if user A comes back again and add new `access token` and `verify token` then the webhook is renewed for new telegram bot

But the previous bot on which i was talking, if i send any message , it starts throwing me error
**A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found**

Things I tried but none of them were able to stop this error to occur

- Deleting webhook
- closing the bot
- logging out the bot

```
telegram_output_obj = TelegramOutput(access_token=access_token)
telegram_output_obj.get_webhook_info()
telegram_output_obj.delete_webhook()
telegram_output_obj.log_out()
telegram_output_obj.close()
```

What actually worked was when i send message to the new bot, it sent me all the responses which came back to the questions i asked on **bot_1** while webhook was changed to serve **bot_2**

Can `telegram_output_obj.stop_polling()` stop this to occur for bot_1, I want all the communication should be closed for bot_1?